# Send item from listview on click on an item's button on uwp

Tags: listview, uwp, uwp-xaml

In my UWP app I have the following code to describe my list view:
[image]

When the delete icon is clicked in an item I want to get the selected item for deleting but I don't know how it should be done.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When the delete icon is clicked in an item I want to get the selected item for deleting but I don't know how it should be done. Thanks in advance

You could insert your item into `ObservableCollection` that could notify the ui interface when item deleted. For more please refer the following.

**Xaml code**

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Items}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    FontSize="15"
                    Text="{Binding}" />
                <AppBarButton
                    Click="AppBarButton_Click"
                    Icon="Delete"
                    Label="Delete"
                    Visibility="Visible" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

**code behind**

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Items.Add($"items{i}");
        }
        
    }
    public ObservableCollection<string> Items { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    private void AppBarButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = (sender as AppBarButton).DataContext;
        Items.Remove((string)item);
    }
}
```

Comment: What does DataContext exactly return?

Comment: `DataContext` type is object, you need inbox it with item's type. above example is string type

Comment: so DataContext would be the item binded in that row of type Item in this case, am I right?